# Is there a way to force pid in upstart script

Tags: ubuntu, python, upstart, uwsgi

I am running a uwsgi-python server under ubuntu 10.04. I use upstart to start/stop a uwsgi daemon(daemonize option is set for uwsgi).

Start and stop commands work fine, but when i try to reload my job, it won't work. The reason for this is that upstart associates wrong pid to my job, which is also a uwsgi process but not a master process. Master process is spawned third(two forks for daemonization) and upstart with expect daemon stanza expects second forked process to be the main.

So I was wondering is there a way to force upsart to associate my job with uwsgi master process ID or any other workaround with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not daemonize under upstart, it is not needed

Comment: Thanks! Removing daemonize option and changing to expect fork seems to work fine